# How to dynamically change info modal innerHTML for each clicked element from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, modal-dialog

I am trying to make a small collection of recipes and four of them are already stored inside an array of objects, each object representing another recipe. My problem is that I want to make an info window, a modal if you will, which will show information about each clicked recipe that's stored inside its object.

The thing is whenever i try to set innerHTML of said modal the for loop I created shows entire object and so far I didn't find out how to make each click on modal show only the info for one recipe. (First link should show the details for the first recipe, second for the second and so on).

I tried a for loop which should dynamically loop content for the info window depending on the clicked element but it shows the entire object and so far I'm not sure what other method would be a better solution.

My array of objects looks like this

```
var recipes = [
{
    key: 0,
    title: 'Pasta Carbonara',
    ingredients: 'etc',
    instructions: 'etc'
},
{
    key: 1,
    title: 'etc',
    ingredients: 'etc',
    instructions: 'etc'
},
and so on (4 objects)
]
```

and my for loop looks like this:

```
function openModal() {
    detailsModal.style.display = 'block';
    var modalContent = document.getElementById('modalInfo');
    var modalBody = ''; 
    for (var i=0; i < recipes.length; i++){
        modalBody += JSON.stringify(recipes[i]) 
    }
    modalContent.innerHTML = modalBody;
}
```

The entire code's here: https://codepen.io/Ellie555/pen/KOwexB

This question is really mundane but if you had any suggestions I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add data attributes to the anchors:

```
<a href="#" data-recipe-index="0">Pasta Carbonara</a>
```

And then using those attributes to instruct your modal code which recipe to load:

```
function openModal(e) {
    detailsModal.style.display = 'block';
    var modalContent = document.getElementById('modalInfo');
    // The critical line:
    var modalBody = JSON.stringify(recipes[parseInt(e.currentTarget.dataset.recipeIndex)]);
    modalContent.innerHTML = modalBody;
}
```

Full code: https://codepen.io/mac9416/pen/BXyPdO

Aside: I would [use `<button>` elements](https://medium.com/@madebyhector/when-does-an-anchor-becomes-a-button-eca8ad5c522c) styled as links instead of anchors for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

Your markup above isn't semantic html since you're not redirect or navigating. So first of all I'd replace `<a href="#">...</a>` tag with `<button type="button">...</button>`:

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="recipes" id="recipeSection">
    <div class="recipe-entry">
      <div class="name"><button type="button" id="0">...</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-entry">
      <div class="name"><button type="button" id="1">...</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-entry">
      <div class="name"><button type="button" id="2">...</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-entry">
      <div class="name"><button type="button" id="3">...</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To answer your question to dynamically change info modal innerHTML for each clicked element from an array!

1. add `id` to each element that will be clicked to associate it with the desired object in your array
2. filter that array based on the click target with its `id`

```
const data = recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.key === Number(event.target.id)); 
modalContent.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data[0]);
```

I forked and modified your code. Here's a working [Demo](https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/RXNBJy?editors=1010).

Note:

If you're not sure about `key` values in your array for each item (i.e. dynamically) you can iterate over it and append it into your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create list from Javascript instead statically create it in HTML.

My code with comments here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bu6tz8?file=index.js